# TS 7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number' for Object.keys of getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, typescript-generics, react-ref

I have this typescript error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'` when attempting to type the key from Object.keys of getElementsByTagName('button').

Here is my code:

```
const buttonElements: HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLButtonElement> = blockRef.current.getElementsByTagName(
  'button',
);
if (buttonElements) {
  Object.keys(buttonElements).forEach((key: string) => {
    buttonElements[key].addEventListener('click', handleOpenModal, false);
  });
}
```

Here I've used type `key: string` within the `forEach()` and I'm getting a type error within `buttonElements[key]`. I've found similar problems that other people have faced and found that using index signature was the solution, however I'm unsure of how to add an index signature or extend the object given that this object is of type `HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLButtonElement>`.

Methods I've tried:

- `buttonElements[key as keyof HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLButtonElement>]`
- `buttonElements[key as string]`
- `const buttonElements: HTMLCollectionOf<string, HTMLButtonElement> = blockRef.current.getElementsByTagName('button',);`

Any help to properly type the `key` or to better type `buttonElements` is greatly appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: You need to convert the key to a number.

Comment: Just make it an array `Array.from(buttonElements).forEach(button => {})` or use querySelectorAll which has forEach `const buttonElements blockRef.current.querySelectorAll("button"); buttonElements.forEach(button => {});`

Answer (score 1):

That is because `Object.keys()` returns an *array of keys*, but `HTMLCollectionOf<>` actually contains an object where *numbers* are used as indices. This means that you need to manually cast the `key` to number (e.g. by using the unary operator `+` as such: `+key`) before using it to access any entry in the `buttonElement` collection:

```
Object.keys(buttonElements).forEach((key) => {
  buttonElements[+key].addEventListener('click', handleOpenModal, false);
});
```

In addition, I would actually recommend against using `getElementsByTagName`, when `querySelectorAll` is a more modern approach and is actually iterable, and you can use `for...of` to iterate through the node list:

```
const buttonElements = blockRef.current.querySelectorAll('button');
for (const buttonElement of buttonElements) {
  buttonElement.addEventListener('click', handleOpenModal, false);
}
```

Comment: "*…and is actually iterable*" - you know, the `HTMLCollection` returned by `getElementsByTagName` is iterable as well!

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate flag for these cases where there is no suitable conversion to `number` for a `string` index, is `noImplicitAny`.

Add the following flag in `compilerOptions` of your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
...

"noImplicitAny": false
...
```

You can learn more at: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny